# Pointer arithmetic, pointer to the end of a container

Tags: c, pointers

If I have a following struct as the metadata

```
typedef struct node
{
    int size;
    char ch;
    char arr[1];
}NODE;
```

Assume `arr`points to an array,which has been allocated exactly `size` of bytes right after `NODE* a` , how can I get the pointer pointing to the end of this array? (the yellow arrow)
[image]

Can I do like following? I'm wondering if `a+size` is counted in terms of bytes?

```
NODE* a;
//some code for memory allocation
NODE* new; // I want this points to the yellow place
new = (NODE*)(a+sizeof(NODE)+size);
```

Comment: Why? You would typically allocate each NODE dynamically, so it wouldn't be adjacent to another one anyway. Or you'd pre-allocate an array of them with some known max size each.

Comment: @jarmod because I'm trying to store the NODE and array in a big char array as simulated memory.

Comment: Then you may need to understand struct alignment for your compiler options and pad each NODE upwards appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic on `a` will happen in units of `sizeof(NODE)`.  To point to the area `size` bytes after that you should cast `a` to `char *` first so pointer arithmetic works one byte at a time:

```
new = (NODE*)((char *)a+sizeof(NODE)+size);
```

Also, for what you're doing you should actually define `NODE` like this:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int size;
    char ch;
    char arr[];
}NODE;
```

This is the modern way of declaring a **flexible array member**.  You also won't have to worry about padding bytes between `arr[0]` and the additional allocated space.

Also note that to traverse an array of `NODE` you can't use simple array notation.  You have to look at each node in sequence to know where one ends and the next begins.

Comment: Legacy code states that `char *arr;` and `char arr[];` should be equivalent definitions of a pointer to  `char` and it is still maintained for parameter declarations.

Comment: Legacy code states that `char *arr;` and `char arr[];` should be equivalent definitions of a pointer to  `char` and it is still maintained for parameter declarations.

Answer (score 0):

In modern C:

```
typedef struct node
{
    size_t size;
    char ch;
    char arr[];
}NODE;

NODE *allocateNODE(size_t size)
{
    NODE *node = malloc(sizeof(*node) + size * sizeof(node -> arr[0]));

    if(node)
    {
        node -> size = size;
    }
    return node;
}
```

then you can access the elements of `arr` simple by

`node -> arr[x]` or `node -> arr + x`

or if you want pointer arithmetics:
`(char *)node + offsetof(NODE, arr) + x;`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you cannot assume `arr` points to some location because `arr` is not a pointer, but an array.  You have declared an array of *one* elemnt, but an array and nothing else.  If you want a pointer, then use pointer notation, declare `arr` as:

```
    char *arr;
```

and then, initialize it as:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int size;
    char ch;
    char *arr;
}NODE;

/* ... */

    NODE *p = malloc(sizeof *p + NUM_CHARS_YOU_WANT + 1); /* 1 more for a '\0' */
    p->arr = (char *)(p + 1);  /* <-- THIS IS THE TRICK!!! */
```

The mistake in your code is to think that `p + n` will be a pointer pointing `n` char positions further than `p`.  But `p` is a pointer to `NODE`, and `p + 1` points to the next element, should you consider it is an array (pointer arithmetic).  So the trick is to move the pointer one step further, and then cast it to the final type.

## NOTE

I've seen a response arguing to use the notation `char arr[];`.  Just to say that that notation can have been adopted by the standard commite to the newest C definition, but is conflicting with the legacy equivalence between defining a pointer as `char *arr;` and `char arr[];` (this equivalence is still maintained in parameter declarations)  If you use that notation, and it means what @dbush maintains in his response, you'll have equivalent code, except that you cannot initialize `arr` (as I do above) as an array cannot be used as a lvalue to assign it a different address.

Comment: A comment indicating the reason of the downvote would be gratefully received.  Mostly when I had not yet finished writing the answer to the question.